# How to get the precision length in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I Need to get the Precision length of the excepted value.

For ex: if my value is 1000343.345
i want output of the length for after dot (345)

Expected output is:: 3
length of 345

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 1000343.345 from dual union all
  3     select     500.2   from dual union all
  4     select    1234     from dual union all
  5     select -239422.13  from dual
  6    )
  7  select col,
  8         length(col - floor(col)) - 1 result       --> this
  9  from test;

       COL      RESULT
----------  ----------
1000343,345          3
      500,2          1
       1234          0
 -239422,13          2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an old trick as subtracting the floored value from the number itself. Then get the length of it and decrease  by 1:

```
select length(1000343.345 - floor(1000343.345)) -1 from dual;
```